# Marginal effects for de-meaned polynomials in mixed models

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, marginal-effects

In the mixed model (or REWB) framework it is common to model within changes by subtracting the cluster mean (demeaning) from a time varying x-variable, see eg.  [(Bell, Fairbrother & Jones, 2018)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11135-018-0802-x). This estimator is basically the same as a fixed effects (FE) estimator (shown below using the sleepstudy data).

The issue arises when trying to model polynomials using the same principle. The equality between the estimators break when we enter our demeaned variable as a polynomial. We can restore this equality by first squaring the variable and then demeaning (see. re_poly_fixed).

```
dt <- lme4::sleepstudy
dt$days_squared <- dt$Days * dt$Days
dt <- cbind(dt, datawizard::demean(dt, select = c("Days", "days_squared"), group = "Subject"))

re <- lme4::lmer(Reaction ~ Days_within + (1 | Subject), data = dt, REML = FALSE)
fe <- fixest::feols(Reaction ~ Days | Subject, data = dt)

re_poly <- lme4::lmer(Reaction ~ poly(Days_within, 2, raw = TRUE) + (1 | Subject),
                      data = dt, REML = FALSE)

fe_poly <- fixest::feols(Reaction ~ poly(Days, 2, raw = TRUE) | Subject, data = dt)

re_poly_fixed <- lme4::lmer(Reaction ~ Days_within + days_squared_within + (1 | Subject),
                            data = dt, REML = FALSE)
models <-
  list("re" = re, "fe" = fe, "re_poly" = re_poly, "fe_poly" = fe_poly, "re_poly_fixed" = re_poly_fixed)

modelsummary::modelsummary(models)
```

The main issue with this strategy is that for postestimation, especially packages that calculate marginal effects (e.g. marginaleffects in R or margins in STATA) the variable needs to be entered as a polynomial term for the calculations to consider both x and x^2. That is using poly() or I() in R or factor notation c.x##c.x in STATA). The difference can be seen in the two calls below, where the FE-call returns one effect for "Days" and the manual call returns two separate terms.

```
(me_fe <- summary(marginaleffects::marginaleffects(fe_poly)))
(me_re <- summary(marginaleffects::marginaleffects(re_poly_fixed)))
```

I may be missing something obvious here, but is it possible to retain the equality between the estimators in FE and the Mixed model setups with polynomials, while still being able to use common packages for marginal effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when a transformed variable is *hardcoded*, the `marginaleffects` package does not know that it should manipulate both the transformed and the original at the same time to compute the slope. One solution is to de-mean inside the formula with `I()`. You should be aware that this may make the model fitting less efficient.

Here’s an example where I pre-compute the within-group means using `data.table`, but you could achieve the same result with `dplyr::group_by()`:

```r
library(lme4)
library(data.table)
library(modelsummary)
library(marginaleffects)

dt <- data.table(lme4::sleepstudy)
dt[, `:=`(Days_mean = mean(Days),
          Days_within = Days - mean(Days)),
    by = "Subject"]

re_poly <- lmer(
    Reaction ~ poly(Days_within, 2, raw = TRUE) + (1 | Subject),
    data = dt, REML = FALSE)

re_poly_2 <- lmer(
    Reaction ~ poly(I(Days - Days_mean), 2, raw = TRUE) + (1 | Subject),
    data = dt, REML = FALSE)

models <- list(re_poly, re_poly_2)

modelsummary(models, output = "markdown")
```

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 295.727 | 295.727 |
|  | (9.173) | (9.173) |
| poly(Days_within, 2, raw = TRUE)1 | 10.467 |  |
|  | (0.799) |  |
| poly(Days_within, 2, raw = TRUE)2 | 0.337 |  |
|  | (0.316) |  |
| poly(I(Days - Days_mean), 2, raw = TRUE)1 |  | 10.467 |
|  |  | (0.799) |
| poly(I(Days - Days_mean), 2, raw = TRUE)2 |  | 0.337 |
|  |  | (0.316) |
| SD (Intercept Subject) | 36.021 | 36.021 |
| SD (Observations) | 30.787 | 30.787 |
| Num.Obs. | 180 | 180 |
| R2 Marg. | 0.290 | 0.290 |
| R2 Cond. | 0.700 | 0.700 |
| AIC | 1795.8 | 1795.8 |
| BIC | 1811.8 | 1811.8 |
| ICC | 0.6 | 0.6 |
| RMSE | 29.32 | 29.32 |

The estimated average marginal effects are – as expected – different:

```r
marginaleffects(re_poly) |> summary()
#>          Term Effect Std. Error z value   Pr(>|z|) 2.5 % 97.5 %
#> 1 Days_within  10.47     0.7989    13.1 < 2.22e-16 8.902  12.03
#> 
#> Model type:  lmerMod 
#> Prediction type:  response

marginaleffects(re_poly_2) |> summary()
#>   Term Effect Std. Error z value   Pr(>|z|) 2.5 % 97.5 %
#> 1 Days  10.47     0.7989    13.1 < 2.22e-16 8.902  12.03
#> 
#> Model type:  lmerMod 
#> Prediction type:  response
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Vincent. I am not sure I follow the last bit, the average marginal effects for both models re_poly and re_poly_2 are the same, and they still differ from the FE-model specified above.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I can't currently think of a good way to do these kinds of post-estimation operations on random effects models with Mundlak-style demeaning. The problem is that `marginaleffects` (and all other alternative packages in the same style) rely on the model formula to figure out which variables to increment when computing slopes or contrasts. So transformations like group-demeaning should not be hard-coded, but I don't know of a clean way to do that in the formula. Sorry for false hopes.

Comment: No worries :) Thanks for excellent work on modelsummary and marginaleffects!

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is not exactly what I asked for in the question. But at least it is a decent workaround for anyone having similar problems.

```
library(lme4)
library(data.table)
library(fixest)
library(marginaleffects)


dt <- data.table(lme4::sleepstudy)
dt[, `:=`(Days_mean = mean(Days),
          Days_within = Days - mean(Days),
          Days2 = Days^2,
          Days2_within = Days^2 - mean(Days^2)),
    by = "Subject"]


fe_poly <- fixest::feols(
  Reaction ~ poly(Days, 2, raw = TRUE) | Subject, data = dt)

re_poly_fixed <- lme4::lmer(
  Reaction ~ Days_within + Days2_within + (1 | Subject), data = dt, REML = FALSE)

modelsummary(list(fe_poly, re_poly_fixed), output = "markdown")
```

We start with the two models previously described. We can manually calculate the AME or marginal effects at other values and get confidence intervals using `multcomp::glht()`. The approach is relatively similar to that of `lincom` in STATA. I have written a wrapper that returns the values in a data.table:

```
lincom <- function(model, linhyp) {

t <- summary(multcomp::glht(model, linfct = c(linhyp)))
ci <- confint(t)

dt <- data.table::data.table(
  "estimate" = t[["test"]]$coefficients,
  "se" = t[["test"]]$sigma,
  "ll" = ci[["confint"]][2],
  "ul" = ci[["confint"]][3],
  "t" = t[["test"]]$tstat,
  "p" = t[["test"]]$pvalues,
  "id" =  rownames(t[["linfct"]])[1])

return(dt)

}
```

This can likely be improved or adapted to other similar needs. We can calculate the AME by taking the partial derivative. For the present case we do this with the following equation: days + 2 * days^2 * mean(days).

```
marginaleffects(fe_poly) |> summary()

  Term Effect Std. Error z value   Pr(>|z|) 2.5 % 97.5 %
1 Days  10.47      1.554   6.734 1.6532e-11 7.421  13.51

Model type:  fixest 
Prediction type:  response
```

By adding this formula to the lincom function, we get similar results:

```
names(fe_poly$coefficients) <- c("Days", "Days2")  
mean(dt$Days)  # Mean = 4.5

lincom(fe_poly, "Days + 2 * Days2 * 4.5 = 0")

   estimate       se       ll       ul        t            p                     id
1: 10.46729 1.554498 7.397306 13.53727 6.733549 2.817051e-10 Days + 2 * Days2 * 4.5


lincom(re_poly_fixed, "Days_within + 2 * Days2_within * 4.5 = 0")
   estimate       se       ll       ul       t p                                   id
1: 10.46729 0.798932 8.901408 12.03316 13.1016 0 Days_within + 2 * Days2_within * 4.5
```

It is possible to check other ranges of values and to add other variables from the model using the formula. This can be done using lapply or a loop and the output can then be combined using a simple `rbind`. This should make it relatively easy to present/plot results.

**EDIT**

Like Vincent pointed out below there is also `marginaleffects::deltamethod`. This looks to be a better more robust option, that provide similar results (with the same syntax):

```r
mfx1 <- marginaleffects::deltamethod(
  fe_poly, "Days + 2 * Days2 * 4.5 = 0")
mfx2 <- marginaleffects::deltamethod(
  re_poly_fixed, "Days_within + 2 * Days2_within * 4.5 = 0")

rbind(mfx1, mfx2)
                                      term estimate std.error statistic      p.value conf.low conf.high
1               Days + 2 * Days2 * 4.5 = 0 10.46729  1.554498  6.733549 1.655739e-11 7.420527  13.51405
2 Days_within + 2 * Days2_within * 4.5 = 0 10.46729  0.798932 13.101597 3.224003e-39 8.901408  12.03316
```

Comment: This is very cool. Thanks for posting. FYI, there's a `deltamethod` function and `hypothesis` argument in `marginaleffects`. Might be useful: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/hypothesis.html

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! That looks much more promising for a robust solution :)